# How to get script level variable in Ajax success function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

In my javascript file, I cannot access script level variable in Ajax success function. See following code:

```
MyApplication.Test = Class.extend({


    ...
    ...

    testElement : null,

    ...
    ...

    updateElementBackground : function(url)
    {
        if(url.length > 0) {
        var response =  $.ajax(url ,{
                     contentType : "application/json",

                     headers: {"Access-Control-Request-Headers": "X-requested-with"}, 
                     type : "GET",
                     success : function(data) {
                          this.testElement.css("backgroundImage","url('"+url+data+"')"); // testElement is undefined now. here this refers to the Ajax call
                     },
                     error : function(e) {
                         errorCallback(e);
                      }
                  });
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    this.testElement.css("backgroundImage","testImage.jpg"); // testElement is accessible here
                  }
    }
});
```

How can I get **"testElement"** in Ajax success function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in the scope. Try to made a var in function like this.

```
MyApplication.Test = Class.extend({


...
...

testElement : null,

...
...

updateElementBackground : function(url)
{   
    var testElement = this.testElement;
    if(url.length > 0) {
    var response =  $.ajax(url ,{
                 contentType : "application/json",

                 headers: {"Access-Control-Request-Headers": "X-requested-with"}, 
                 type : "GET",
                 success : function(data) {
                      testElement.css("backgroundImage","url('"+url+data+"')"); // testElement is undefined now. here this refers to the Ajax call
                 },
                 error : function(e) {
                     errorCallback(e);
                  }
              });
              }
              else
              {
                this.testElement.css("backgroundImage","testImage.jpg"); // testElement is accessible here
              }
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When you try to get `this.testElement`, you access `this` of `success` function. And there is no `testElement` property.

Try to predefine `this` in `updateElementBackground` scope.

```
updateElementBackground : function(url)
{
    var that = this;        
    var response =  $.ajax(url ,{
          success : function(data) {
               that.testElement.css("backgroundImage","url('"+url+data+"')"); 
          },
       });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two main approaches to solving this, the first as covered by deadulya is to store the value in a local variable in the parent function scope.

The other option would be to proxy the success function to ensure that it runs in the context of your class.

```
success: $.proxy(function(data) {
    ...
}, this),
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set context for `updateElementBackground` to your class instance. In Backbone it would be something like this:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    testElement: $(...),

    initialize: function(parms){
        this.updateElementBackgroundCallback = _.bind(this.updateElementBackground , this);
    },

    events: {
        'click .something': 'updateElementBackgroundCallback'
    },

    updateElementBackground: function(){
        this.testElement.css(...);
    }
});
```